# Can't boot win7 after installing ubuntu 12.04 how can i restore my win7?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I use flash disk to install my ubuntu 12.04 under win7 system, however i made a stupid mistake when I later know that I cant choose install ubuntu alongside with win7 (should choose advanced mode), however, after installing successfully, I find win 7 option on booting page, but after I choose it I.The system told me to insert a win7 CD and choose 'restore' option. ignore it to keep on, the mistake shows. and one more thing I can see files that originally in my D disk in win7. I'm rookie and don't know what to do, I have read some questions related but can not follow.

My intention is to find my files in win7. I want to ask questions specifically:

- How to get back to win7 ? Do I necessarily need to reinstall win7 and choose 'restore' option? Whether files in win7 are erased?
- What is I install ubuntu again and do the right step? will it help?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 install has corrupted the Win7 boot loader(Usually it only corrupts the boot loader, not the whole OS partition). This happened to me too.

What you need to do now is to repair the Win7 boot loader. You can do that with a Win7 installation disk, by running the start-up repair utility. This will only repair the start-up files necessary for Win7 and WILL NOT erase all your files. (If you get to a point where you are trying to repair this and the computer tells you all your files will be lost, then you most probably shouldn't go ahead with it, and first try start-up repair)

These links should help you with the start-up repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639595

On the other hand if accessing Win7 isn't so urgent and you only need to access files on your C: or D: drive, try mounting them in ubuntu and access them from ubuntu.

PS. reinstalling Ubuntu will not do you any good. Nor will uninstalling it. It is better to have one OS running on your computer than none.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I use a win7 installation disk to     repair my system. everything works fine until a startrep.exe error happen. it says 0*fbc9ca53 reference 0*916160c5 memory disk cannot be read. and i can not forward. it seems that i can only change ubantu grub ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know about that error. You should search google and Windows 7 forums for help and details. If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept and upvote it.